# How can I access to functions after firebase serve

Tags: node.js, firebase, ssl, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm testing on my machine using firebase.
After `firebase serve`
I can access to function with HTTP only:
http://localhost:5001/project/us-central1/endpoint

But, when I try to get parameter.

```
export const basicHTTP = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const name = req.params.name
  res.send(`Hi, good! ${name}`)
})
```

I cannot retrieve any params. I think I have to access my localhost as https.

But my local environment doesn't provide the way to access through SSL.
How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator makes the HTTPS Cloud Function available on both HTTPS **and** HTTP on local host. So you can call it on HTTP from your code.

From the documentation on [connecting to HTTPS functions in the emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions#https_functions):

> Each HTTPS function in your code will be served from the local emulator using the following URL format:

> ```
> http://$HOST:$PORT/$PROJECT/$REGION/$NAME
> ```

> For example a simple helloWorld function with the default host port and region would be served at:

> ```
> https://localhost:5001/$PROJECT/us-central1/helloWorld
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response and help. But I found the descriptions from Official docs before. so, 

`http://localhost:5001/project_id/us-central1/basicHTTP`

this is works to me. but when I've changed to https

`https://localhost:5001/project_id/us-central1/basicHTTP`


Chrome browser refuses to access with an error.


This site can’t provide a secure connection 

localhost sent an invalid response.

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: this error in localhost is caused because usually on localhost we don't have SSL certificates installed.If you are using Chrome you can allow the host on the advanced options of the error page.